# jQuery highlight malfunctioning with jquery 1.8.2 and jquery custom 1.8.24

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-effects

I have the jQuery UI on my site so im using jquery 1.8.2, and jquery custom 1.8.24.
I am wondering why this code for a jquery highlight effect

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#comment" + 33).click(function () {
         $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
     });
 });
```

does not work on my website.
the id comment33 is a  element.
please may you help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6mMNX/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#comment" + 33).click(function () {
        $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Your code works. Check for dependencies if all your libraries are added correctly.